# How to make ereg_replace replacement work

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I have this code:

```
if ($this->serv == "shoutcast")
    $sp_data = ereg_replace("^.*<SHOUTCASTSERVER", "<SHOUTCASTSERVER", $sp_data);
```

And it gives me the normal error: `Deprecated: Function ereg_replace() is deprecated in`

I replaced with:

```
if ($this->serv == "shoutcast")
    $sp_data = preg_replace("/^.*<SHOUTCASTSERVER/", "/<SHOUTCASTSERVER/", $sp_data);
```

No errors now, but it doesn't work as expected:
http://img833.imageshack.us/img833/4409/8lck.png

working with errors:
http://img89.imageshack.us/img89/2669/6wft.png

Comment: What does `$sp_data` look like?

Comment: for($i = 0; $i < 30; $i++) {
    if(feof($sp))
     break;
    $sp_data .= fread($sp, 31337);
    usleep(500000);

Comment: That doesn't tell me anything. I mean litterly, what does that string look like?

Comment: Thank you putvande, the answer below is the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regexp should work. The only possible issue I see is that you have new line before `<SHOUTCASTSERVER`, try using [`s` modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php):

> If this modifier is set, a dot metacharacter in the pattern matches
>   all characters, including newlines. Without it, newlines are excluded.
>   This modifier is equivalent to Perl's /s modifier. A negative class
>   such as [^a] always matches a newline character, independent of the
>   setting of this modifier.

```
preg_replace("/^.*<SHOUTCASTSERVER/s", "<SHOUTCASTSERVER", $sp_data);
```

And if you're working with XML you should consider using [XML manipulation class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.xml.php), for example (my personal favorite) [`DOM`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php).

Comment: Thank you it worked, but i just change one thing:               "<SHOUTCASTSERVER" removing the /